# extract string between last forward slash and first period

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to extract string after the last "/" and first "." in excel using one formula.  I tried below and it works how can I combine them into one formula?

## get string after last “/”

=MID(A1,FIND("=",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","=",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))+1,256)

## Get string before first “.”

=MID(B1,1,FIND(".",B1)-1)

Comment: Substitute every instance of B1 with the whole code from the first formula, since that's what you would have been working with in the second case anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=REPLACE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "/", REPT(" ", LEN(A1))), LEN(A1))), FIND(".", TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "/", REPT(" ", LEN(A1))), LEN(A1)))), LEN(A1), "")
```